# difference between Wilcoxon test in R and Python

Tags: python, r, scipy

I'm trying to run the Wilcoxon test both in R and in python's scipy.stats package. However I get different results can anyone explain?

My Code in R

```
    > des2
 [1]  6.2151308  4.7956451  4.7473738  5.4695828  6.3181463  2.8617239
 [7] -0.8105824  3.9456856  4.6735000  4.1067193  5.7656002  2.2237666
[13]  1.0354143  4.9547707  5.3156348  4.8163154  3.4024776  4.2876854
[19]  6.1227500
> wilcox.test(des2, mu=0, conf.int = T)

    Wilcoxon signed rank test

data:  des2
V = 189, p-value = 7.629e-06
alternative hypothesis: true location is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 3.485570 5.160925
sample estimates:
(pseudo)median 
      4.504883
```

my code in Python:

```
test = [6.2151308, 4.7956451,  4.7473738,  5.4695828,  6.3181463,  2.8617239, -0.8105824, 3.9456856,  4.6735000,  4.1067193, 5.7656002, 2.2237666, 1.0354143, 4.9547707, 5.3156348,  4.8163154,  3.4024776,  4.2876854,  6.1227500]
z_statistic, p_value = wilcoxon(np.array(test) - np.log(1.0))
print "one-sample wilcoxon-test", p_value


one-sample wilcoxon-test 0.000155095772796
```

Even though the p-value for both of them is low enough to reject the null hypothesis, the p-value have a difference of 3 order of magnitude and I can't understand why

Comment: The docs of scipy tells us: `Because the normal approximation is used for the calculations, the samples used should be large` - The docs of `wilcox.test` says: `By default (if exact is not specified), an exact p-value is computed if the samples contain less than 50 finite values and there are no ties. Otherwise, a normal approximation is used.` Not sure if this is the only difference, though.

Comment: I'm using Wilcox because i dont want an normal approximation...therefore I should use the R version right?

Comment: R's test does not approximate the p-value. This is crucial for small sample sizes.

Comment: @cel Your comment should probably be the answer.  scipy doesn't have the exact test (but there is some work towards it in a pull request on github).

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser, do you happen to know the ticket id? It would be awesome to have a link here.

Comment: I think it's OK if the underlying data is not normally distributed, you just need enough samples. The normal distribution is an approximation to the distribution of rank sums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scipy`'s implementation always uses a normal approximation when calculating the p-value. While this certainly works for large sample size `n`, the p-value can deviate from the true p-value for small sample sizes.

In the notes of `scipy`'s [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.wilcoxon.html) you find:

> Because the normal approximation is used for the calculations, the
>   samples used should be large. A typical rule is to require that n >
>   20.

---

`R`'s implementation calculates an exact p-value for small sample size and uses the normal approximation only for sufficiently large `n`.

R's [docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/wilcox.test.html) tell you:

> By default (if exact is not specified), an exact p-value is computed
>   if the samples contain less than 50 finite values and there are no
>   ties. Otherwise, a normal approximation is used.

So in short: When the two p-values differ, `R`'s p-value should be preferred.